# Как проверить имя и фамилию через одну функцию

Tags: javascript, html, css, функции, frontend

https://jsfiddle.net/gej9582z/

есть функция validName . она проверяет имя и фамилию на валидность. В параметре nameID передается id инпута ('surname' или 'name'). То что не прошло валидацию получает класс incorrect-forms (добавляется красный border).

В случае, если оба инпута валидны функция nameNext продолжается.

```
function nameNext(){
    validName('name');
    validName('surname');
    if(nameIncorrect == true && surnameIncorrect == true){
            //код
        }
}
```

И вот тут у меня возникла проблемка. Не могу найти в чем ошибка. При ошибке 1 из инпута оба получают класс incorrect-forms. И вообще фунцкия nameNext не продолжается.

```
let nameIncorrect = true;
let surnameIncorrect = true;
function validName(nameID){
    let value = document.getElementById(nameID).value;
    if(/^[a-z ,.'-]{2, 20}$/i.test(value) == false){
        if(nameID == 'name'){
            nameIncorrect = false;
            document.getElementById(nameID).setAttribute('class','reg-forms large-forms incorrect-forms');
        }
        else{
            surnameIncorrect = false;
            document.getElementById(nameID).setAttribute('class','reg-forms large-forms incorrect-forms');
        }
    }
    else{
        nameIncorrect = true;
        surnameIncorrect = true;
    }
}
```

Помогите исправить

Comment: покажите тело функции validName

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gej9582z/

Comment: Похоже у вас проверка даст всегда false. Каков алгоритм проверки? Валидации?

Comment: if(/^[a-z ,.'-]{2, 20}$/i.test(value) == false){

Comment: То есть фамилию и имя всегда латинскими вводить?

Comment: @MuhiddinShamsiddinov а если validName('name'); убрать то тоже оба поля?

Comment: @Leonid да,  только латинскими

Comment: @DemoS нет, тогда ток фамилия, кстати даже когда правильно ввожу фамилию

Comment: Убрал пробел из вашего выражения и получил тру, только все черное стало))

Comment: имя и фамилию принято не проверять. Разве что длину.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё свёл в одну функцию. Добавил подсветку сразу обоих полей в случае неверности обоих, а также снятие подсветки с одного или обоих полей. Проверку оставил только буквы, - и пробел.

Блок событий, происходящих если проверку проходим громоздкий, но туда я не лез. Лучше просто блоками и скрывать такие вещи. Если их будет несколько и постепенно переходишь от одного к другому, то надо их организовать единообразно, условия проверки каждого поля можно хранить в data-validation и data-valtype атрибутов соответствующего поля, чтобы можно было программно считывать условия и проверять единой функцией. Можно и действие изменения прописывать в data-...

Так очень быстро запутаетесь. Обрабатывайте блоками. А не каждое поле.

Нет смысла писать `== false` или `==true`, любое выражение преобразуется к булевому типу согласно некоторым правилам. `if(!x)` или `(x)`. В вашем случае вообще метод .test явно возвращает true/false, как и переменные хранят булевы значения.

---

```js
function nameNext(){
    let name = document.getElementById('name');
    let surname = document.getElementById('surname');
    let pattern = /^[a-z- ]{2,20}$/i;
    let toBeMarked = [];
    let toBeUnmarked = [];
    if(pattern.test(name.value) && pattern.test(surname.value)){
        document.getElementById('name-block').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('name').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('surname').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('sex').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('name-button').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('bdate-block').style.display = 'flex';
        document.getElementById('bdate-block').setAttribute('class','reg-block zoomIn');
        document.getElementById('country').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('bday').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('bmonth').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('byear').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('bdate-button').style.display = 'block';
        toBeUnmarked = [name, surname];
    } else if(!pattern.test(name.value) && !pattern.test(surname.value)){
      toBeMarked = [name, surname];
    } else {
       toBeMarked = pattern.test(name.value) ? [surname] : [name];
       toBeUnmarked = pattern.test(name.value) ? [name] : [surname];
    }
    
    toBeMarked.forEach(inp => {inp.setAttribute('class','reg-forms large-forms incorrect-forms')});
    toBeUnmarked.forEach(inp => {inp.setAttribute('class', 'reg-forms large-forms')});       
}
```

```css
*{
margin:0px;
padding: 0px;
}
body{
background-color: #000000;
}
button, input{
outline: none;
}
h1, h3, span, button, input{
font-family: Comfortaa;
}
#intro-block{
widows: 100%;
height:100%;
background-color: #000;
justify-content: center;
}
#intro-title{
font-size: 100px;
font-weight: 100;
color:white;
text-align:center;
padding: 300px 0px 40px 0px;
text-shadow:0 0 2px #ffffff;
z-index:99;
}  
#logo{
width:100%;
font-size: 25px;
font-weight: 100;
color:white;
text-align:center;
padding: 20px 0px 40px 0px;
text-shadow:0 0 3px #ffffff;
letter-spacing: 5px;
}
#block{
width:100%;
height:100%;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: center;
z-index:0;
}
#title{
width:100%;
font-size: 50px;
font-weight: 100;
color:white;
text-align:center;
padding: 220px 0px 40px 0px;
text-shadow:0 0 3px #ffffff;
z-index:0;
}
.sign-button{
width: 250px;
height:40px;
background: #285dcf;
border:none;
border-radius: 20px;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 18px;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-weight:500;
cursor: pointer;
box-shadow: 0 0 2px #636363;
z-index:0;
margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}
#start-login-button{
  width:150px;
  height:40px;
}
#main-reg-block{
width:100%;
height:100%;
justify-content: center;
}
.reg-block{
justify-content: center;
flex-wrap: wrap;
width:480px;
height:160px;
background-color: #0e0e0e;
border-radius: 40px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 10;
}
#name-block{
  height:250px;
}
#bdate-block{
  height:200px;
}
#confirm-block{
  height:300px;
}
.reg-title{
width:100%;
font-size: 22px;
color:#fff;
font-weight:400;
text-align:center;
margin-top: 15px;
}
form{
display:flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
width: 450px;
height: 300px;
padding: 20px;
justify-content: center;
}
.reg-forms{
height:40px;
border:none;
border-radius: 10px;
background-color: #ffffff;
text-align:center;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 400;
margin:5px;
}
.large-forms{
width:410px;
}
.incorrect-forms{
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #f32525;
}
.bday{
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#bday{
width: 100px;
}
#bmonth{
width:150px;
}
#byear{
width:140px;
}
.reg-button{
width: 160px;
height:30px;
background: #285dcf;
border:none;
border-radius: 20px;
color: #ffffff;
font-size: 17px;
font-weight:500;
cursor: pointer;
margin: 5px 0px 10px 250px;
}
#confirm-description{
  font-size:14px;
  color:#ffffff;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-weight: 100;
}
a{
  color:#3e2cdd;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#confirm-agreement{
  font-size:14px;
  color:#ffffff;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-weight: 100;
}
#submit{
margin: 0px 0px 0px 250px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes zoomIn {
from {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
  transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
}
  
50% {
  opacity: 1;
}
  }
  
@keyframes zoomIn {
from {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
  transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
}
  
50% {
  opacity: 1;
}
  }
  
  .zoomIn {
-webkit-animation-name: zoomIn;
animation-name: zoomIn;
animation-duration: 0.3s;
}
  @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
from {
  opacity: 0;
}
  
to {
  opacity: 1;
}
  }
  
  @keyframes fadeIn {
from {
  opacity: 0;
}
  
to {
  opacity: 1;
}
  }
  
  .fadeIn {
-webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
animation-name: fadeIn;
animation-duration: 1s;
  }
```

```html
<div class="reg-block" id="name-block">
            <h3 class="reg-title" id="name-title">Как вас зовут?</h3>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="reg-forms large-forms" id="name" autocomplete="cc-name" onkeyup="enter('name-button')" placeholder="Имя" />
            <input type="text" name="surname" class="reg-forms large-forms" id="surname" autocomplete="cc-family-name" onkeyup="enter('name-button')" placeholder="Фамилия" />
            <input type="text" name="sex" class="reg-forms large-forms" id="sex" autocomplete="sex" onkeyup="enter('name-button')" placeholder="Пол" />
            <button class="reg-button" id="name-button" onclick="nameNext()">Продолжить</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: Была бы польза)

Comment: Старайтесь задавать `let correct = false`,  а не `let incorrect = true`, двойное отрицание путает в дальнейшем.

Comment: @Leonid Хороший ответ. Доступно и понятно.

Answer (score -1):

Немного упростил ваш код. Очень много всего лишнего было

```js
function validName(nameID){
  let field = document.getElementById(nameID);
    let value = field.value;
    
    let isValid = /^[a-z ,.'-]{2,20}$/i.test(value);

    if(!isValid){
        field.setAttribute('class','reg-forms large-forms incorrect-forms');
    }
    
    return isValid;
}

function nameNext(){
    if(validName('name') && validName('surname')){
        document.getElementById('name-block').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('name').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('surname').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('sex').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('name-button').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('bdate-block').style.display = 'flex';
        document.getElementById('bdate-block').setAttribute('class','reg-block zoomIn');
        document.getElementById('country').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('bday').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('bmonth').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('byear').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('bdate-button').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

```css
*{
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
body{
    background-color: #000000;
}
button, input{
    outline: none;
}
h1, h3, span, button, input{
    font-family: Comfortaa;
}
#intro-block{
    widows: 100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: #000;
    justify-content: center;
}
#intro-title{
    font-size: 100px;
    font-weight: 100;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 300px 0px 40px 0px;
    text-shadow:0 0 2px #ffffff;
    z-index:99;
}  
#logo{
    width:100%;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 100;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 20px 0px 40px 0px;
    text-shadow:0 0 3px #ffffff;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
}
#block{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    z-index:0;
}
#title{
    width:100%;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 100;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 220px 0px 40px 0px;
    text-shadow:0 0 3px #ffffff;
    z-index:0;
}
.sign-button{
    width: 250px;
    height:40px;
    background: #285dcf;
    border:none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight:500;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px #636363;
    z-index:0;
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}
#start-login-button{
  width:150px;
  height:40px;
}
#main-reg-block{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    justify-content: center;
}
.reg-block{
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width:480px;
    height:160px;
    background-color: #0e0e0e;
    border-radius: 40px;
    margin-top: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
}
#name-block{
  height:250px;
}
#bdate-block{
  height:200px;
}
#confirm-block{
  height:300px;
}
.reg-title{
    width:100%;
    font-size: 22px;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:400;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
form{
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    width: 450px;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 20px;
    justify-content: center;
}
.reg-forms{
    height:40px;
    border:none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin:5px;
}
.large-forms{
    width:410px;
}
.incorrect-forms{
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #f32525;
}
.bday{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#bday{
    width: 100px;
}
#bmonth{
    width:150px;
}
#byear{
    width:140px;
}
.reg-button{
    width: 160px;
    height:30px;
    background: #285dcf;
    border:none;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight:500;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 5px 0px 10px 250px;
}
#confirm-description{
  font-size:14px;
  color:#ffffff;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-weight: 100;
}
a{
  color:#3e2cdd;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#confirm-agreement{
  font-size:14px;
  color:#ffffff;
  margin-left: 20px;
  font-weight: 100;
}
#submit{
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 250px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes zoomIn {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
      transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
    }
  
    50% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  
@keyframes zoomIn {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
      transform: scale3d(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
    }
  
    50% {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  
  .zoomIn {
    -webkit-animation-name: zoomIn;
    animation-name: zoomIn;
    animation-duration: 0.3s;
}
  @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  
  @keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  
    to {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
  
  .fadeIn {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-duration: 1s;
  }
```

```html
<div class="reg-block" id="name-block">
                <h3 class="reg-title" id="name-title">Как вас зовут?</h3>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="reg-forms large-forms" id="name" autocomplete="cc-name" onkeyup="enter('name-button')" placeholder="Имя" />
                <input type="text" name="surname" class="reg-forms large-forms" id="surname" autocomplete="cc-family-name" onkeyup="enter('name-button')" placeholder="Фамилия" />
                <input type="text" name="sex" class="reg-forms large-forms" id="sex" autocomplete="sex" onkeyup="enter('name-button')" placeholder="Пол" />
                <button class="reg-button" id="name-button" onclick="nameNext()">Продолжить</button>
            </div>
```

Comment: Ну а проблема была в регулярке. Вот тут {2, 20} не должно быть пробела

Comment: Ну а что означает [a-z ,.'-]? и чем это отличается от .  (<-- там просто точка)?

Comment: @Leonid точка в квадратных скобках - это точка. А вне их - любой символ

Comment: ТОЧКА!!!! но для чего же она нужна в имени и фамилии?

Comment: Здесь не показывает, то оба поля неверны. Узнаешь об этом только по второму нажатию. Это так бесит!!!!